# Memory limits of Sub Routines in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a memory limit to the size of the stack accessible to VBA Sub Routines?

For some odd reason, when I `Dim` 6 or more `Range` variables, I get the error that there's no more room in the stack.

I could see `Range`'s being  memory intensive, especially the larger non-contiguous ones I'm using, but I'm curious if there's a best practice to avoid the error.

Example:

```
Dim RR As Range
'Dim TestArea As Range
'Dim foremenList As Range
'Dim workerList As Range
'Dim workers As Range
'Dim Foremen As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim R As Range
Dim EmplList(0 To 100) As Variant




'Set TestArea = Sheet90.Range("b4:q8, b15:q19, b26:q30")
'Set foremenList = Sheet90.Range("V24:V30")
Set RR = Sheet90.Range("v24:x45")
i = 0
```

If I uncomment those declarations, I get the error. If I leave them commented I do not.

The only other code in the sub is:

```
For Each R In RR.Cells
   If Len(R.Value) > 0 Then
       'EmplList(i) = R.Value
       i = i + 1
    End If
Next R
Sheet90.Range("b40").Value = "Test3"
```

For reference this is Excel VBA running in Excel 2010 on a Windows 7 laptop with 8GB of RAM. Not a monster, but not a slouchbox either.

Comment: Have never seen that, and have often used more ranges than 6...  Something else is likely the issue.

Comment: Are you using any deep recursions in your sub?

Comment: No recursion, one for loop. Question edited to add more code.

Comment: When does the error occur?

Comment: strange you would not get the error with type `Variant` (undeclared). It's still a `Range` object in memory, and `Variant` typically is slower to process since compiler needs to *determine* what type of object it is anyways...

Comment: The `Sub` is triggered on change of Sheet90, where it's located. That doesn't cause a recursion issue though because I started from just changing a single value on edit, and it never failed until I added the ranges.

Comment: @DavidZemens I have not tried it with 6 `Variants` yet.

Comment: Are you doing `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the beginning of this sub?  If not, and you're manipulating cells on the sheet, each of those manipulations triggers the `_Change` event and that's potential recursion problem or infinite loop.

Comment: Agree with @DavidZemens - The line `Len(R.Value) > 0` triggers a `_Change` event (tested)

Comment: There's the issue. Thanks Ioannis and DavidZemens. Disabling events when the event triggers, and then re-enabling at the end of the sub fixed the problem. If either of you wants to post an answer, I'll upvote/accept.

Comment: Add OPTION EXPLICIT as the first line of your code and try again. I'm sure it will either start working or you get an informative error message which you can post here and I can update the answer accordingly. Also use the debug viewer and the call stack to see what's going on, where the code fails. Oh! And stack limit for scripting host is 512Kb but it has nothing to do with VBA :P

Comment: I'm not certain that `Len` triggers a `_Change` event, at least it does not when I test it. But a further line where you assign `Sheet90.Range("b40").Value = "Test3"` will certainly trigger the `_Change` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @David Zemens and I pointed out in the comments,  statements like `Sheet90.Range("b40").Value = "Test3"` look innocent but actually trigger events.

Another thing to note: some statements trigger "double events", like drag and drop. It is actually two events, triggered by one action. In this case, after the drag, events are fired, the drop is executed and events re-fire. This (drag and drop)  has caused me pain in the past..

**EDIT**: My initial statement was erroneously referring to `Len(R.Value) > 0`, which does not trigger recalculation. It is the last line that triggers the recalculation. Thanks to David for pointing out!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not able to get the `Len` statement to trigger an event when I test this, but a line further in your code certainly will trigger the `_Change` event:

`Sheet90.Range("b40").Value = "Test3"`

This will drive an infinite loop, as each time this assigns a value to `B40`, the change event is triggered again, and again, and again...

Comment: You are right, I put the break point at wrong line :) `R.Value` does not trigger recalculation, I will edit my response.